# Assign ' in string

Tags: plsql

I have the following value that needs to be assign into string -

```
ABC'DEFGH
```

How I can assign the sign of ' into string? 
example -

```
str := 'ABC'DEFGH'
```

Comment: Change to 'ABC\'DEFGH' or use "ABC'DEFGH"

Comment: @SPlatten those won’t work in Oracle. There is no escape character for quotes and double quotes aren’t used for string literals.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson technically, isn't a single quote the escape character for a single quote?

Comment: @Boneist you are right of course.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson phew! You had me questioning my whole existence then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as with plain SQL: to escape a single quote, double it.

```
str := 'ABC''DEFGH';
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the quoted string: `q'<delimiter character><string<closing delimiter character>'`, e.g.:

```
str := q'{ABC'DEFGH}'
```

You can use a variety of characters as the quote delimiters. For more information, see [the documentation for information on text literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218), which includes how to use the q operator.